# Is Load Balancing possible in this case?

Tags: networking, tomcat, load-balancing

Our Web Application will be in production soon. We are going to use Load Balancing for this *WAR* for more redundancy.

I am a Java developer, so please excuse if my question with respect to load balancing is basic.

Right now the *WAR* is deployed on two Linux  servers (`Server A` and `Server B`).

These two servers have TomCat installed with similar directory structures.

The *WAR* will be using a property file defined under the `tomcat/bin` directory and this property value is different for these two servers.

These two servers have different IP addresses.

Please let me know if Load Balancing will be any issue in this case ?

Comment: That should be quite easy. The documentation even has configuration examples: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/loadbalancers.html

Comment: Did you try it? we can't really be expected to guess if this will work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be an issue if you don't expect users' sessions to persist across the two servers.  For example, if a given user is logged in and in session of the web app and suddenly that server goes down, you would expect the load balancer to transparently transfer the user to the other server.  This by default would result in a new session being created on the other server's tomcat instance, hence making the user lose their session data (if not persisted in the DB), have to re-login, etc.

Typically you can configure the app servers and the load balancers to enable sticky sessions so that the single session is can be maintained across the farm.  This setup is typically more complicated.  So if you don't have a requirement to have the session carry across the two instances, you should be ok.